# I have an element i attached animation to, so i want the animation to take effect after i have hovered on the element. How can i do that?

Tags: css, animation, hover

```css
img{
filter:brightness(20%)
animation-name:f;
animation-duration:5s;
}
@keyframes f{
50%{filter:brightness(150%)
}
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
    <img src="http://www.sololearn.com/images/tree.jpg">
  <body>
<html>
```

I want the animation effect to take effect when i hover on the image

Answer (score 3):

use `:hover` pseudo class on `img`

```css
img{
  filter:brightness(20%);
  animation-duration: 5s;
}

img:hover {
  animation-name: f;
}
  
@keyframes f{
   50%{ filter: brightness(150%); }
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.sololearn.com/images/tree.jpg">
```

Comment: Thanks Yousaf, i appreciate your answer.